# Is there way to see my progress percentage in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

I'm playing Undertale, and I wonder my progression percentage. I saw some pictures of people with pretty high loves (levels). I want to reach higher loves to get more HP, but I don't want to kill everyone too.

Is there a way to see my progression percentage in-game or in a website etc?

Comment: By website, I mean something like "if you last did this, you are about at %50 of the game".

Comment: If you want to get a higher HP without killing anyone, sleeping at the Snowdin inn raises it a little.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way in-game to view your progress percentage.

A good way to judge it is based on the number of areas in the game. There are 4 major areas in the game, and 6 bosses, all roughly evenly spaced. Using this, you can approximately figure out where you are in the game.

Answer (score 7):

Undertale is a rather short game, and progress counters wouldn't necessarily be the most helpful thing in terms of game progression. Undertale is stylized in a way that you can feel when the end is nigh. But just saying, if you last fought a long-haired gal with gills and a penchant for aggressiveness , then you're about 50% done.

Just saying, LOVE isn't all there is to life.

Comment: I urge you to remove that last line. It not only gives things away but also sets the reader up for a less rewarding experience with the game.